# how to move apps to SD card on Galaxy A15

Tags: applications, samsung

apps are consuming a lot of space on my internal storage so I decided to buy a new memory card to where I intend to migrate all the apps to installed on internal storage to it but then I have tried selecting all the apps and then check if there is a menu with the option to move the apps to SD card but the android 11 OS does not even show any kind of menu on selecting multiple apps. How do I move apps to SD card to save on space?